# Pop from a Python list with default value

Tags: python, list, idioms

Is there a way to pop an element from a list with a default value if the index does not exist? I know that for dictionaries, python allows the pop function to return a default value as shown:

```py
d = {"stack": "overflow"}
d.pop("stack", 10) # returns "overflow"
d.pop("badkey", 10) # returns 10
```

Is there an equivalent for lists? It seems python's default list pop method [does not support default values](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/list/pop.html) so what is the most pythonic way to implement the functionality shown in the code snippet below?

```py
def pop_default(input_list, index, default_value):
    try:
        temp = input_list[index].copy()
        del input_list[index]
    except IndexError:
        return default_value
```

Comment: Note that while @DeepSpace gave a correct answer to your question, the fact that you are even trying to do this might point to a problem in your program's design. Repeated pops from a list, unless done only on locations very close to the end of the list, are extremely expensive.. You may want to find a way to process your list sequentially, without repeatedly popping from it, or use a different data structure.

Comment: I'm trying to make a quick script that gets command line arguments using sys.argv while also storing default arguments. While I know argparser can take care of this, I'm looking for a quick solution to process these arguments without overcomplicating the code.

Comment: The efficient way to do this would be to iterate over the list, and create two new lists - one of options, and another of free-standing arguments. Then again, the really efficient way of doing will be using `argparse` or `optparse`.

Answer (score 3):

What's with the `copy` and `del`? just try to `pop`, and catch the `IndexError`:

```
def pop_default(input_list, index, default_value):
    try:
        return input_list.pop(index)
    except IndexError:
        return default_value
```

If are going to do that a lot of times in your codebase you can use a subclass (however it might be more confusing so it might be better to just use the above function)

```
from collections import UserList

class MyList(UserList):
    def pop(self, index, default_value=None):
        try:
            return super().pop(index)
        except IndexError:
            return default_value


my_list = MyList(['a'])
print(my_list.pop(0))
print(my_list.pop(0, 'default'))
```

Outputs

```
'a'
'default'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would go with the one liner:

```
out = a.pop(a.index(value)) if value in a else default
```

where `a` is your list.

if you are given an index, then

```
out = a.pop(index) if index >=(len(a)-1) else default
```

EDIT:

After @Andrew's observation to account for negative index, the one-liner version would result as:

```
out = a.pop(index) if -len(a) <= index <= len(a)-1 else default
```

Comment: But `.pop` input is an index, your suggestion's input is a value. You can fix it by checking the `len`

Comment: My pop input is the `a.index(value)`, that is, the integer index where that value is found, if it is found.

Comment: but the input **is** `value`. It's impossible to use your snippet if `value` is not provided

Comment: if you are given an index, then `out = a.pop(index) if index >=(len(a)-1) else default`

Comment: This works in some cases but doesn't account for negative indexing. `-len(a) <= index <= (len(a)-1)` would account for that